Ant design vue upload-dragger prompt if for than max count files are uploaded
I have the below code in Vue3 app using ant design Upload Dragger
<a-upload-dragger
    :showUploadList="false"
    accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf"
    name="file"
    :multiple="true"
    v-model:fileList="fileList"
    :max-count="10"
    class="orginal-upload-dragger"
/>

by default if I select more than 10 documents it selects only 10 documents. However I want to show a prompt error in case more than 10 documents are selected.
